# How to add HTML Block to Merchant Tribe while Customizing theme

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add "Html Block" to Home Page while customizing theme, I am trying to add for HOME PAGE2 Section but I can't find any way to add HTML Block.

Comment: can you describe more about you'r problem?

Comment: I want to add a HTML block to my Home Page for "Merchant Tribe", As it is predefined control that only needs to be added to the page by selecting, I can find other controls like image rotator but not "HTML Block" as I want to add some HTML I need to add HTML block to achieve it.